# Add header in ChildView from ExpandableListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview, header, expandablelistview, children

I'm trying to find a solution for my answer through the Internet but I can't find a good one. I looked this topic: [Android ExpandableListView Child Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577624/android-expandablelistview-child-headers) but it doesn't work for me.

What I have now (Screen):

[image]

And my code is:

```
private void fillData() {
    ExpandableListView lv;
    lv = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grades_view);
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.list_header, null);
    lv.addHeaderView(view, null, false);

    dbh = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    MyExpandableListAdapter mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(
            getActivity(), dbh);
    mAdapter.synchronize();
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
}

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<Subject> mSubjects = new ArrayList<Subject>();
    private List<List<Course>> mCourse = new ArrayList<List<Course>>();
    private DatabaseHelper dbh;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, DatabaseHelper dbh) {
        this.dbh = dbh;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void synchronize() {

        mSubjects = dbh.getSubjects();

        for (Subject s : mSubjects) {
            mCourse.add(dbh.getCourses(s));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mCourse.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Course c = (Course) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child,
                    parent, false);

        TextView txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        txt.setText(c.getCode());
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ects);
        txt1.setText(String.valueOf(c.getEcts()));
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grade);

        if (c.getGrade() == -1) {
            txt2.setText("-");
        } else {
            txt2.setText(String.valueOf(c.getGrade()));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mCourse.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mSubjects.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mSubjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return mSubjects.get(groupPosition).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Subject s = (Subject) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                    false);

        TextView txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txt1.setText(String.valueOf(s.getName()));
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.semester);
        txt2.setText(String.valueOf(s.getSemester()));

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

As we can see, to put the first-level header (Name and Sem) I used:

```
View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.list_header, null);
lv.addHeaderView(view, null, false);
```

But I don't know how to do the same with the children (a header with Code, ECTS and Grade).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an "extra child"

```
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        if (childPosition == 0)
            return null;

        return mCourse.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        if (childPosition == 0)
            return 0;

        return getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (childPosition == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child, null);

            // your special header

            return convertView;
        } 

        // rest of your method

    }
```

Where you can have a different layout or whatever you like.

Answer (score 5):

1.-Include the header in your xml of group, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    //Your elementsof group
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/headerList"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    //the elements of your header (ID,counter, description, etc..)
</LinearLayout>
```

2.-Now, with that ID in your method getGroupView()...

```
LinearLayout headerList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.headerList);
    if(isExpanded)
        headerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        headerList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

A year later, i hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The  above Solution of Guillermo Orellana Ruiz  will  work fine  , but Note that only if " **"extra child"**  is  added to the array of child elements to the  0th postion,then only all exact child elements will be displayed ,otherwise  one child element will be missing, if you are not adding one  **extra child** to the  0 th position to the child array or child elements,,

What happens from my understanding from my task,is that when an "extra child" is added the 0th position takes that "extra child" and that  child will not be displayed, instead of that "extra child" the header  view is displayed, this is done by  :

```
      if (childPosition == 0) {
       // your header
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child, null);            

        return convertView;
    }
```

Also please note  that **extra child**  adding to the  child array must stay in the  0th position other wise  the extra child will be displayed in your child list view and your actual data in the  0th position will not be displayed

I just mentioned  this  because  when i used this code for my task, one of the child elements was not displaying,it was  missing and i wondered for a while  ,so it took  some time for me  to understand this , so i just post this as a  Note so that people who use  the accepted answer must not waste his/her  time .